Create Super User issue in django
My model is like below.
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractUser

# Create your models here.

class User(AbstractUser):
    GENDER_CHOICES = (
        ('M', 'Male'),
        ('F', 'Female'),
        ('O', 'Other'),
    )

    USER_TYPE = (
        ('S', 'Super Admin'),
        ('A', 'Admin'),
        ('P', 'Patient'),
        ('D', 'Doctor'),
        ('U', 'User'),
    )

    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    date_of_birth = models.DateField(null=True, default=None)
    gender = models.CharField(max_length=1, choices=GENDER_CHOICES)
    user_type = models.CharField(max_length=1, choices=USER_TYPE)
    username = models.EmailField(unique=True)
    email = models.EmailField(unique=True)
    phone = models.CharField(max_length=15, blank=True, null=True)
    address = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    active = models.BooleanField(default=True)

    
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = ['email', 'password']


    def __str__(self):
        return f"{self.first_name} {self.last_name}"

I am trying to run this command.
python manage.py createsuperuser


I am getting errors
Username: admin@admin.com
Password: 
Password (again): 
The password is too similar to the username.
This password is too common.
Bypass password validation and create user anyway? [y/N]: y
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/foysal/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 105, in _execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "/home/foysal/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/db/backends/sqlite3/base.py", line 329, in execute
    return super().execute(query, params)
sqlite3.IntegrityError: NOT NULL constraint failed: hospital_user.date_of_birth

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/foysal/Documents/pYtHoN/hospital_management/manage.py", line 22, in <module>
    main()
  File "/home/foysal/Documents/pYtHoN/hospital_management/manage.py", line 18, in main
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/home/foysal/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 442, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/home/foysal/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 436, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "/home/foysal/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 413, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
  File "/home/foysal/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/management/commands/createsuperuser.py", line 89, in execute
    return super().execute(*args, **options)
  File "/home/foysal/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 459, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "/home/foysal/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/management/commands/createsuperuser.py", line 238, in handle
    self.UserModel._default_manager.db_manager(database).create_superuser(
  File "/home/foysal/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/models.py", line 172, in create_superuser
    return self._create_user(username, email, password, **extra_fields)
  File "/home/foysal/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/models.py", line 155, in _create_user
    user.save(using=self._db)
  File "/home/foysal/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/base_user.py", line 78, in save
    super().save(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/foysal/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 822, in save
    self.save_base(
  File "/home/foysal/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 909, in save_base
    updated = self._save_table(
  File "/home/foysal/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 1067, in _save_table
    results = self._do_insert(
  File "/home/foysal/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 1108, in _do_insert
    return manager._insert(
  File "/home/foysal/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/db/models/manager.py", line 87, in manager_method
    return getattr(self.get_queryset(), name)(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/foysal/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 1847, in _insert
    return query.get_compiler(using=using).execute_sql(returning_fields)
  File "/home/foysal/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py", line 1823, in execute_sql
    cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "/home/foysal/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 122, in execute
    return super().execute(sql, params)
  File "/home/foysal/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 79, in execute
    return self._execute_with_wrappers(
  File "/home/foysal/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 92, in _execute_with_wrappers
    return executor(sql, params, many, context)
  File "/home/foysal/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 100, in _execute
    with self.db.wrap_database_errors:
  File "/home/foysal/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 91, in __exit__
    raise dj_exc_value.with_traceback(traceback) from exc_value
  File "/home/foysal/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 105, in _execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "/home/foysal/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/db/backends/sqlite3/base.py", line 329, in execute
    return super().execute(query, params)
django.db.utils.IntegrityError: NOT NULL constraint failed: hospital_user.date_of_birth



I consider the code is completely correct. Are you sure that you migrated the model updates to the Database before you create user?

Thanks @yxzlwz. Yes, may be I migrated the model updates to the Database before create user. Thanks.

Try settings birthday field to "null=True, blank=True, default=date.today". then makemigrations, then migrate, then try creating user. Later, you can remove the "date.today" to None.

You missed "USERNAME_FIELD", I think, put it in your User model
